# javascript - access and change the value of the var from outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ho can I access and change the value of `var` from outside the function?

```
    var ArrowFlag = "1";

     $('input, textarea, select').focusin( function() {
        var ArrowFlag = "0"; 
        //console.log(ArrowFlag) will = 0
     });

    $(document).bind('keyup', function() {
    // When input:focus console.log(ArrowFlag) will = 1
    });
```

When you have `input:focus` event, var `ArrowFlag` should have a value of `0`.

But, when you have `keyUp` event after `input:focus` var ArrowFlag value will be `1`. Why? Look like my var `ArrowFlag` never had it's value changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined two seperate variables called `ArrowFlag`, if you want them to be the same variable remove the var from the one inside the focusin callback:

```
 var ArrowFlag = "1";

 $('input, textarea, select').focusin( function() {
    ArrowFlag = "0"; 
    //console.log(ArrowFlag) will = 0
 });

$(document).bind('keyup', function() {
    // after focusin ArrowFlag will now be 0
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/yyLPE

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I have change that. But, still when `onKeyUp` `ArrowFlag = "1"` - looks like my `focusin()` is ignored.

Comment: @NewUser Works fine in the example I have added to my answer

Answer (score 3):

This is all about variable scope.
Remove the "var" from `var ArrowFlag = "0"`, and take a read of http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/ or one of the many [other articles](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript%20scope) about it - you'll be glad you did.

Comment: OK. I have change that. But, still when `onKeyUp` `ArrowFlag = "1"` - looks like my `focusin()` is ignored.

Comment: Put an `alert('!');` or, better, a `console.log('!');` (if you use firebug or the Chrome console, etc) into the focusin() function to see if it is being called.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript variables are scoped to functions, you're declaring another `ArrowFlag` inside the `focusin` anonymous function that hides the outer `ArrowFlag`. You do not need to declare `ArrowFlag` again (by using `var`), try the following:

```
var ArrowFlag = "1";
 $('input, textarea, select').focusin( function() {
    ArrowFlag = "0"; 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

`var` declares a variable in the current context, the top context being the DOM window.

Drop the `var` in the function to avoid redeclaring a variable of same name in a different context.